# How can I call a parent route from a page generated by a nested route in nodejs

Tags: node.js, express, handlebars.js

I am using handlebar JS, nedb database and express framework. My project has nested routes like `categories/news/recent`. The problem is with the link I created in a view of nested route.
Sample view: `<a href="/categories">return to categories</a>`

But the link directs to `/categories/news/recent/categories` rather than  `/categories`

How can I fix this?

EDIT: Including sample code

route: simulations.js

```js
app.get('/bio/:sim_id', (req, res, next) => {
  const sim_id = req.params.sim_id

  db.simulations.find({ _id: sim_id }, (err, docs) => {
    res.render('simulations/simulation', { data: docs })
  })
})
```

view: menu.hbs

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="phy">Physics</a></li>
  <li><a href="che">Chemistry</a></li>
  <li><a href="bio">Biology</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: what you have tried , share your coed here

Comment: please see the edited question